# Show list of states depending on user selection

Tags: javascript, ajax, comparative-review, databinding

I have some data that needs to bind to my view depending on the user selection.

Example: changing the list of states in a dropdown depending on the selected country.

My understanding is, there are two ways to do this:

1. Have a global JS variable, say,
   `var model`, which has a property, `"states"`. This contains all the relevant data of states.

So, I bind the data from the `"states"` property of the `model` variable depending on the selection of country.

Code:

In my view:

```
<select name="state" ></select>
<select name="country" >
   <option value="US" >USA</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="CN" >CHINA</option>
   <option value="IN" >INDIA</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //Model is my C# object that I am converting into a JS object
</script>
```

In my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    stateSelection(model.StateList)
})

function stateSelection(stateList) {
        var jStates = jQuery('select[name="state"]');
        var selectedCountry = jQuery('select[name="country"] option:selected').val();
        var provinceExists = false;
        jStates
                .children()
                .remove()
                .end()
        if (stateList.length > 0) {
            jQuery.each(stateList, function (key, val) {
                if (selectedCountry === val.ID) {
                    jStates
                        .append('<option value="' + val.Value + '"  class="' + selectedCountry + '" >' + val.Text + '</option>');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

2. Make an ajax call whenever the country dropdown selection is made, then pass the country name/id as parameter and get a response object that contains the list of states that I want to display, and bind them to my view.
   In my JS:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: Home/GetStates,
       data: $('select[name="country"] option:selected').val(),
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
       },
       success: successFunction
   });

   function successFunction(data) {
       stateSelection(data) //data contains the list of states
   }
   ```

My question basically is, is it bad practice to have a rather large JS object (list of states) as a global variable - or does it make sense to get only the data I need from my server, only when I need it.

I'm trying to understand which one would be the better approach and under what conditions. Or is there a better alternative?

Update:

I tried both and found that loading the data into my DOM was the better way. Not only was the user experience seamless but it helped me avoid writing additional server side code and database calls. Loading the states into my browser did not have any noticeable impact on the front end performance if anything we thought it was better user experience - no loaders - no ajax calls. Thanks to everyone who answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question about downloading all options at once versus fetching the state options dynamically using ajax, the answer depends on just how big the state list is, but *probably* the right answer is to download them all at once.

#### File Size Considerations

Consider that jquery, which you are already including, is about 30KB minified and compressed.  My guess would be that your state list is small compared with that, so you shouldn't worry about downloading the whole thing at once.  If that assumption is wrong, then ajax *might* be a reasonable choice.

#### UX Considerations

Think about the user experience when the entire state list is downloaded.  Making a new a country selection will instantly repopulate the states -- a seamless experience.  If you have to use ajax, there will be a pause between the user's country selection and when the states become available.  This is awkward, and ideally, if you do this, you'd display an ajax spinner (or some other indication that you are waiting for a network response).  This will make your code more complex, and can be difficult to get exactly right.  For example, you'd need to make sure you handle errors gracefully, and show appropriate messages to the user.  If you don't use ajax, you simply avoid all these issues.

So my advice would be to avoid ajax unless you really need it -- eg, your state lists are *huge* and you know you'll be supporting users with slow connections.

Answer (score 2):

> My question basically is, is it bad practice to have a rather large JS object (list of states) as a global variable - or does it make sense to get only the data I need from my server, only when I need it.

Depends on the case. You *can* do either. You just have to optimize the approach.

- If you load the data with the page, make sure your server responds fast enough, the source minified and transmission gzipped. Even with all that, you must also account for the processing overhead.
- If you load the data with AJAX. Same principles apply regarding processing, transmission and size, but now with 2 separate requests. The only difference is that you can tell the user something's loading rather than a blank screen.

In the end, I suggest you profile your application. Know what the actual bottleneck is and fix that bottleneck. In the end, there is always another problem that's bigger than load speed, usually maintainability.

Another way of dealing with your dilemma is to just jam your countries and state data into one JSON file, with state data embedded in the country data. Then just AJAX that entire file into the page. The twist is you just have to make sure that the browser caches that file for a long time. That way, further requests read from the cache, saving the browser all the waiting. Of course, there's that first-load wait.

Now off to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

jQuery has a shorthand for this: `$(function(){ ... })`

```
function stateSelection(stateList) {
```

You can put this function inside the ready handler. That way, the function isn't global.

```
    var jStates = jQuery('select[name="state"]');
```

Not sure why you'd use `jQuery` here when you just used the shorter `$` earlier. Also, why prefix `j` to `jStates`? Is it because it's a jQuery object? It's like saying "prefix 'b' for booleans, or 'n' for numbers." Variables are variables regardless of what value they hold. Remove that `j`.

```
    var jStates = jQuery('select[name="state"]');
    var selectedCountry = jQuery('select[name="country"] option:selected').val();
```

If these elements don't change over the life of the page, store their reference in a variable instead of doing it every function call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Home/GetStates,
    data: $('select[name="country"] option:selected').val(),
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    },
    success: successFunction
});
```

There's a shorthand for this: `$.post(...)`.

Additionally, what you're doing here is not a "create" operation, so don't use `POST`. You're merely asking the server for states, a "read" operation. `GET` is more appropriate for that.

Another thing is that `success` and `error` are older ways of handling success and error. You should start using the promise interface of jQuery's ajax operations. It goes like `$.get(...).then(successFn, failFn)`.

```
jQuery.each(stateList, function (key, val) {
  if (selectedCountry === val.ID) {
    jStates.append('<option value="' + val.Value + '"  class="' + selectedCountry + '" >' + val.Text + '</option>');
  }
});
```

Why does it look like this loops through an entire list and picks out a state based on a country? Does this mean your list contains states other than those from the selected country? Why? Since you already passed to the server the selected country, why not let the server filter off the states for you to trim down the data sent down the wire?

Seeing this makes me wonder, why the need for an AJAX call when you just loaded all your data into `model`?

---

Now if I understood the code correctly, the following should be a more "optimized" alternative:

```
$(function () {

  // Cache a reference to the selects
  var countriesSelectBox = $('select[name="country"]');
  var statesSelectBox = $('select[name="state"]');

  countriesSelectBox.on('change', function(){

    var selectedCountry = countriesSelectBox.val();

    $.get('Home/GetStates', { data: selectedCountry }).then(function(states){

      // Assuming states is just a list of states for the selected country
      $.each(states, function(index, state){

        // A cleaner way of creating a jQuery DOM object, and assigning values
        $('<option />', {value: state.value, class: selectedCountry }).text(state.Text);

        // empty() is like .children().remove()
        statesSelectBox.empty().append(option);
      });
    });
  });
});
```